# Change ul background color whose li has a specific class

Tags: css

I have a `ul` list whose `li` has a specific class. I want to change the back ground color of that `ul`.

Eg:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">About us</li>
    <li class="">Why Join?</li>
    <li class="">Constitution</li>

</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">2016 Conference</li>
    <li class="">Member Home Page</li>
    <li class="">Bulletin Board</li>
</ul>
```

I want to change second `ul` background color.

I have tried following code

```
ul.dropdown-menu li.active {
    background-color: #e9124a !important;
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to set the background of the parent `ul` of an active `li` element?

Comment: yes i want to change the color of 2nd ul whose li has active class

Comment: @PrashantSharma That's not possible.

Comment: with only CSS ( Cascading Style Sheets ) you can select ONLY from TOP to BOTTOM of the HTML structure. not the other way. so you CAN'T select an element based on it's children .

Comment: how about this: https://jsfiddle.net/o39baeta/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this...

I think you cannot do it without the help of Javascript

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].parentElement.style.background = '#e9124a';
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="">About us</li>
  <li class="">Why Join?</li>
  <li class="">Constitution</li>

</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="active">2016 Conference</li>
  <li class="">Member Home Page</li>
  <li class="">Bulletin Board</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good job with JavaScript DOM Nodes handling!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the 2nd `ul` element:

```css
.dropdown-menu:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #F0D0D0;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">About us</li>
    <li class="">Why Join?</li>
    <li class="">Constitution</li>

</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">2016 Conference</li>
    <li class="">Member Home Page</li>
    <li class="">Bulletin Board</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to select all the ul who contains a `li` with class `active`, as far as I know it is not possible with only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

with CSS ( Cascading Style Sheets ) you can select ONLY from TOP to BOTTOM of the HTML structure. not the other way. so you CAN'T select an element based on it's children .

you can do this with a simple jQuery see snippet below

```js
$("ul").has("li.active").css("background-color","#e9124a ")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">About us</li>
    <li class="">Why Join?</li>
    <li class="">Constitution</li>

</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">2016 Conference</li>
    <li class="">Member Home Page</li>
    <li class="">Bulletin Board</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

> There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.
>   In the meantime, you'll have to resort to JavaScript if you need to select a parent element.

Comment: Please flag as a duplicate if you the answer is on another post. Also, this isn't a forum, and those aren't 'threads'.

Comment: It's not actually the answer, it's just a more generic question, but it would give this guy a clue.

Comment: It *is* an answer. A rule of thumb: if most of your post is quoted from another post and almost exactly answers it, flag as duplicate.

Comment: OK, will do from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

you can add a new class for the second ul.
e.g.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="">About us</li>
    <li class="">Why Join?</li>
    <li class="">Constitution</li>

</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu new-color">
    <li class="active">2016 Conference</li>
    <li class="">Member Home Page</li>
    <li class="">Bulletin Board</li>
</ul>

ul.dropdown-menu li.active {
    background-color: #e9124a !important;
}

//setting the color of the second ul
.new-color {
    background-color: #c6ffb3 !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding a class to `ul` doesn't mean the `ul` contains `li.active`